# How to encrypt and decrypt database credentials when using in spark and production environments

Tags: apache-spark

Currently, I have hard-coded the jdbc connection parameters which is really not a good practice.Is there a way where we could encrypt and decrypt the connection parameters when using in a spark job?

Thanks,
Sai

Comment: Unfortunately, that thread doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Maybe this [link](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/108918/implementing-data-integrity-check-using-spark-jdbc.html) about using Hadoop Credentials API would provide some hints.